# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'webdriver'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> **AttributeError**: 'module' object has no attribute 'webdriver'

why this error happen when write

```
import selenium
```

and when write code like this no error happen

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: `import selenium` works fine in my case. Can you show the full error message?

Comment: it was work for me until i install komodo and get error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fady\Desktop\sad.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'webdriver'

Comment: Quick check. Have you by any chance created a file called `selenium.py`?

Comment: no and file name is sad.py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get an error because `webdriver` is a module inside the `selenium` module, and you can't access modules without an explicit import statement.

If you take a look at `help(selenium)`, you'll see there are two modules and one non-module contained inside.

```
PACKAGE CONTENTS
    common (package)
    selenium
    webdriver (package)
```

And it behaves according to what I described above:

```
>>> selenium.common # doesn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'common'
>>> from selenium import common # works
>>> selenium.selenium # works
<class 'selenium.selenium.selenium'>
>>> selenium.webdriver # doesn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'webdriver'
>>> from selenium import webdriver # works
>>>
```

Comment: but code was working before install komodo ide 
i try to reinstall python  but the error still happen