# How to understand docs and use the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been struggling for a while understanding the documentation of any module:

I want to use the `selenium` module.

Looking at the documentation, I can't really implement anything.

Given this part of the Docs API : http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver

I see this : `class selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(...)`

When I try implementing this in my python code it says : `AttributeError: module 'selenium' has no attribute 'webdriver'`

python 3.x code:

```
import selenium
browser = selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='C:/Users/chromedriver')
```

Can someone explain me how to read,understand and use any piece of documentation?

Comment: How can we explain how to read and understand?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's far too broad, and not about programming as defined by the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to explain how to read 'any piece of documentation' (I don't think anyone can). However, I can help you in the good direction by giving you an idea of how *I* start with new modules.

Normally, each module not only has a documentation part but also a 'Getting Started' part: which is [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) for `selenium`.

It is only when I have the feeling that I understand the basics of the module that I go and read the docs for fine-tuning what I really wanted to do. As you said: they are hard to read.

====================================================

In this specific case:

```
import selenium
browser = selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='C:/Users/chromedriver')
```

results in

> AttributeError: module 'selenium' has no attribute 'webdriver'

However, following the ['Getting started' tutorial](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

works fine. This works, because `webdriver` is not an attribute to the module `selenium` but a [module itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801823/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-webdriver). This means that you have to call it explicitly to use it. (This is very implicitly noted at the top of the documentation page: *Recommended Import Style* (showing `from selenium import webdriver`).)

Using Google Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
```

works also fine, and this example is given by [Google itself](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started).

Comment: hmm... The thing is I followed the `docs` and implemented the chrome webdriver as it is said, but it doesn't work...

Every module is object oriented. I imported the class `selenium` and then I called the function `WebDriver` and assigned to `browser` variable, and why does it give me an error?

What am I doing wrong? And Why the `WebDriver` is so nested?

Comment: I have added some extra explanation why `import selenium; selenium.webdriver` doesn't work but `from selenium import webdriver` works.